# Powershell Resolve-DnsName to variable

Tags: powershell, nslookup

I'm trying to put data of Resolve-DnsName mmydomain.com to a variable.

```
$data = Resolve-DnsName mmydomain.com 
Write-host $data
```

As a result of this scrip, I can see only this string `Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.DnsRecord_A`, while simple execution of `Resolve-DnsName mmydomain.com` writes me full nslookup data.

Any advice, please?

Comment: `Write-Host ($data |Out-String)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP information is in `$data.IPAddress` - the below lists ALL the properties that are retrieved when you run the `Resolve-DnsName` cmdlet:

```
$data = Resolve-DnsName mmydomain.com 
$data | Select *
```

If you want one(or more) of the properties, ask for it(them) by name:

```
$data = Resolve-DnsName mmydomain.com 
# By Select method
Write-Host 'Select the IpAddress property of $data:'
$data | Select IPAddress | Out-Host
# By property name
Write-Host 'Get by property name:'
$data.IpAddress
```

Generally you would just use what you need e.g.

```
$Data | select Name,Ip4Address,Type
```

So in your example:

```
If ($data.IpAddress -like "*11.22.33.44*") {
    Write-Host "Got it!"
}
Else {
    Write-Host "Nothing found!"
}
```